# Remove fields and validations for street and city in checkout

Tags: magento2

I am trying to remove street and city field from checkout on Magento 2.3.5-p1 but the validation is throwing me an error for required city and street. I have tried to add a value in the DB eav_attribute for city and street but nothing. I have added lines in billing and shipping at vendor/magento/module-checkout/... False for city and street as mentioned in other questions here on stack but nothing... Did anyone has a working solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will only set the value as not required on the back-end, but still the validation process will go thru and will receive that street and city is required so the customer won't be able to place an order.

You have to overwrite `checkout_index_index.xml` in `/magentoroot/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout`

After that you need to create a custom module that will set a value to city and street so it can pass the validation process. The values are stored in the Database at table `eav_attribute`, there you have to set the default value of city and street so the module you created will get the value from there.

At the end you can just hide those fields and the customer would not need to fill them. Deleting them is not recommended because these fields are used to create orders, invoices and many other stuffs.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `attribute_code` LIKE 'city' ORDER BY `attribute_id` DESC

And Check and change value  is_requred is 1 to 0